# Trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ converges by using the direct comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I know that if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $ 0 \le a_n \le b_n$. Then if $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

I am having trouble finding a convergent $\sum b_n$ for which
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}} \le \sum b_n
\end{align*}
Is it possible to do it with comparison test, or do I need another method?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{n^2}\le \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$, and $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Well since $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is a p-series $(f(x)= \frac{1}{x^p})$ where $p = 2$ then the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare, as said in the comments, by
$$
\frac1{n^2}<\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n
\text{ so that } ~~
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\le1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n-1}-\frac1n=2$$
by telescoping the upper bound. A closer bound is
$$
\frac1{n^2}<\frac1{(n+1)(n-1)}=\frac1{2(n-1)}-\frac1{2(n+1)}
\text{ so that } ~~
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\le1+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}=\frac74
$$
where the telescoping "leap-frogs".

You could also use the construction of the Cauchy condensation test where
$$
\frac1{n^2}<\frac1{4^k}~~\text{ for }~~ 2^k\le n < 2^{k+1} ~~
\text{ so that } ~~
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^k\cdot \frac1{4^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}=2$$

Answer (score -1):

We know $$n^2 > (n - 1)^2$$

Inverting the fractions the sign changes and we get

$$n^2 > (n - 1)^2 \implies \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{(n - 1)^2}$$

Take $b_n = \frac{1}{(n - 1)^2}$

Hence $a_n < b_n$ is satisfied.

P-series are of the form $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^p}$$

And when $p > 1$ the series converges; $p \le 1$ the series diverges.

Since $b_n$ is a p-series with $p > 1 (= 2)$, $b_n$ converges.

Since $b_n$ converges and $b_n > a_n$; $a_n$ converges as well.

Comment: Is this not rather circular? The upper bound is essentially the same series, only shifted one position.

Comment: Your are basically proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ is convergent by using the fact that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ converges.